# Show that $(1+1/n)^a\to 1$ when a > 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am unable to prove this. $1 + 1/n\to 1$ since $1/n\to 0$, but how do we show that it also converges to $1$ when it is raised to a positive real power?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Sorry, fixed the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the definition of limits. For all $\epsilon>0$, let $$N=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\sqrt[a]{1+\epsilon}-1}\right\rfloor.$$ Then for all $n>N$, we have $$1<(1+1/n)^a<\left(1+1/\frac{1}{\sqrt[a]{1+\epsilon}-1}\right)^a=1+\epsilon.$$ The construction of $N$ is just from the inequality $(1+1/n)^a<1+\epsilon$ we want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also do is consider this as a function $f(x)=(1+1/x)^a$ where $a>0$ and calculate the $\lim_{x\to \infty}{(1+1/x)^a}=lim_{x\to \infty}{e^{a\ln(1+1/x)}}$.

Now by calculating the $\lim_{x\to \infty}{(1+1/x)}$ which equals $1$ you can say that $a\ln(1+1/x)\to0$ and so $e^{a\ln(1+1/x)}\to1$